# Twitter API returns a blank page

Tags: jquery

I remember using this code to get tweet status a couple of months ago.

```
var url =  "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/stackoverflow.json";
$.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", null, function(tweets) {
    for(i in tweets) {
        tweet = tweets[i];
        $("#tweet-list").append(tweet.text + "<hr />");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g67vM/

Now it just doesn't work due to an API change.

Can anybody tell me what to change in that jsfiddle and possibly add a comment or two to show how you did it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Twitter API version 1 is deprecated. You'll get the same results with:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=stackoverflow
```

But, you cannot retrieve API results without authentication anymore. See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth

Comment: wow! are there examples that demonstrate twitter authentication?

Comment: Yes, but most of those examples are in a server-side language. Unless you are using node.js on your server, you won't make it with JavaScript alone. So, in what language would you like an example? PHP?
See this discussion for why it isn't safe to authenticate clientside only: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/5025

Comment: naah I am just getting started with client-side. So let me wrap my head around it first ;)